# Как округлить все числа с запятой?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, как выглядит сейчас. Столбец `answer` имеет тип данных `nvarchar`

| answer | c_num_value |
| --- | --- |
| 9.037 | null |
| 9 | 9 |
| Текст | null |

Код:

```
case when ISNUMERIC(Replace(Replace(answer,'.',''),'-','')) = 1 and LEN(answer) < 3  then 
    CAST(round(answer, 0) as numeric(18,0)) 
end as c_num_value
```

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы результат был таким:

| answer | c_num_value |
| --- | --- |
| 9.037 | 9 |
| 9 | 9 |
| Текст | null |

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=00c187219fb6547d48cf9892a36db475

Answer (score 0):

Не увидел, что len < 3, хотя длина `answer` = 5.

```
case when ISNUMERIC(Replace(Replace(answer,'.',''),'-','')) = 1 and LEN(answer) < 6  then 
    CAST(round(answer, 0) as numeric(18,0)) 
end as c_num_value
```

Comment: Лучше держаться подальше от функции `ISNUMERIC()`. Это дает много ложных срабатываний на «+», «-» и т. д. Лучше использовать решение, подобное показанному @Akina.